# Method overload with unit of measure

Tags: f#, trigonometry, units-of-measurement

I'm noobing around with F# trying to create overloads of `cos` that accepts angles with units.

This is my code:

```
[<Measure>] type rad
[<Measure>] type deg
let toRad(x:float<deg>) =
    (float x) * 3.14159265 / 180.0
    |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<rad>
let cos (angle: float<rad>) = cos(float angle)
let cos (angle: float<deg>) = cos(toRad angle) // get duplicate definition of cos here
```

Compiler complains about duplicate definition of cos on the last row.

Comment: and what goes wrong (if anything)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measure types are erased (see the [specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818979)), so you effectively have two definitions of `cos(angle: float)` which causes the error.

You could create a union type for the two possibilities

```
type Angle = Degrees of float | Radians of float
```

or give the functions different names.